# Nightwatch - wait for text of an element

Tags: javascript, refresh, nightwatch.js

I am new to Nightwatch & JavaScript and need some help with a nightwatch test: Here is what I want to do:
Step 1.refresh browser, 
Step 2. check textValue of an element .

Repeat step1 then step2 until given timeout or textValue of element is same as expected value.

I have been trying to use while looping, however it didn't solve the problem. Here is what I have been working on for some time now.

```
function waitForText(browser) {
    var sent = false;
    var time = new Date();
    time.setTime(Date.now());
    while (!sent && (new Date().getTime() - time) < browser.timeout * 30) {
        var status = "Sending";        
        browser.refresh();
        browser.getText('#elementId', function (result) {
            status = result.value;
            if (status.indexOf("Sent") == 0) {
                sent = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```